# Populate Select from PHP Function in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, select, populate

I have a form shown below:

```
<?php
$list_id = $db_connect->get_results($db_connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE wp_ID= %d AND svr_region=%d', $wpid, 1));
?>
<form name = "reset_data" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">                       
    <select id = "select_id" name="select_id" required>                               
        <option value="" > - Chose ID - </option>                                 
        <?php
        foreach ($list_id as $list_id) {
            $get_list_id = $list_id->ID;
            $get_list_name = $list_id->name;
            echo '<option value="' . $get_list_id . '" >[' . $get_list_id . '] ' . $get_list_name . '</option>';
        }
        ?>                                
    </select>                             
    <select id = "select_role" name="select_role" >                             
        <option value="" > - Chose Role - </option>                           
        <?php
        $get_role = GetRoleList($_POST['select_id']);
        echo $get_role;
        ?>                              
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Data! &#187;"/>                     
</form>
```

How do I create a JQuery to disable `#select_role` if `#select_id` has an empty value.

`#select_id` value type is Integer, and after `#select_id` chosen, it will execute a PHP function `GetRoleList ( $_POST['select_id'] )` and returns the result like this `'<option value="' . $nick_str . '" >' .$nick_str. '</option>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) for this like,

```
$(function(){
    $('#select_id').on('change',function(){
        if(this.value){
           var val=this.value;
           $.ajax({
               url:'your php url here',
               type:'post',
               data:{select_id:val},
               success:function(response){
                  $('#select_role').prop('disabled',false)
                                   .html(response);
               }
           });
        } else {
            $('#select_role').prop('disabled',true);
        }
    });
});
```

Your PHP Page Code,

```
<?php             
     $get_role = GetRoleList ( $_POST['select_id'] ) ;         
     echo $get_role ;
?>
```

And if you want the `select-role` drop down should be disabled on page load then you can use `$get_role variable` like,

```
<select id = "select_role" name="select_role" <?php if !$get_role echo 'disabled="disabled"';?>>
   <option value="" > - Chose Role - </option>
   <?php echo $get_role ; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your info, but i still got blank value fro $get_role, seems it not load the $_POST['select_id'], but for disable and enable the selection it was work.

Comment: Sory i forgot to mention, this problem use on Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the best way to check the values and set the property as required. **Alternatively** could count the number of `option` tags that will be appended to the `<select id="select_id">` and then disable the other `select` if the value is one or less. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var count = $('select#select_id option').length;
        if (count <= 1) { //since 1 will be by default
            //denotes that there is only one option value
            $('#select_role').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
```